# how to get only subdocument from document query in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get only subdocument out of whole document via mongoose in node.js.
My database schema is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// var Items = require('./items.js');

var Items = new Schema({
    no_of_times_ordered:Number,
    item_name:String,
    item_tag:String,
    item_category:String,
    item_stock:Number,
    item_price:Number,
    item_img:String,
    item_illustrations:[String],
    item_liked:Boolean,
    no_of_likes:Number
},{ versionKey: false });


var FoodTruckSchema = new Schema({
    foodtruck_name:String,
    foodtruck_location:String,
    foodtruck_rating:Number,
    foodtruck_tag:String,
    foodtruck_timing:String,
    foodtruck_cusine:String,
    foodtruck_img:String,
    foodtruck_logo:String,
    item_list: [Items]
},{ versionKey: false });



module.exports = mongoose.model('foodtruck',FoodTruckSchema);
```

The query is as given below:

```
var popularitems = function(req,res) {
    foodtr.find(function(err,items){
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json({
            status : '200',
            message:'popular items list',
            data: items
        });
    });
```

So I have already put query where items with foodtrucks are retrieved, but how can I only have items in response?

Comment: show the query which you have tried till now?

Comment: I have put the query that I have tried in updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` or `projection` in your find query to get only `items`.

Try this:

```
foodtr.find({},{'item_list':1},function(err,items){ 
    if (err) res.send(err); 
    res.json({ 
        status : '200',
        message:'popular items list', 
        data: items 
    }); 
});
```

`{}` is similar to query condition, in this case it will retrieve all the documents.
`{'item_list':1}` is to tell mongo to retrieve only `item_list` array(_id comes in default along with anything else).

Hope this is what you want.